# Windows Media Center Plugin

Tags: .net, plugins, windows-media-center

it is possible to make own plugin to media center in windows (in .NET)?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft have a [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895967.aspx) for Windows Media Center. This is probably the best place to start. I also found this link:

> [How To Build An Add-In For Windows Media Center Edition 2005](http://blogs.msdn.com/mcreasy/archive/2004/10/12/241449.aspx)

That should get you started.

Answer (score 7):

here's a link that work for the sdk version 6 for win 7
[win7 mc sd](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=542fc60e-f3c4-43a0-8dad-b8f14a485a74)